# Iterating input value in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I need to create an cluster and outlier analysis for each field in my shapefile.

How can I create an iterator that changes the input value in each run?

[image]

Comment: You always want the input value to be a field or a value?

Comment: I want a field. Put a different field in each run

Answer (score 1):

I dont belive it is possible to iterate over fields in modelbuilder. It is however possible with a python script.

Example:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\TEST.gdb'

#change to match your field names and add/remove fields:
fieldlist = ['Field1','Field2','Field3']

for field in fieldlist:
    arcpy.ClustersOutliers_stats(Input_Feature_Class='inputfc', Input_Field = field, Output_Feature_Class='Outputfc'+field, .... #add all other paramaters
```

For complete syntax see [Cluster and Outlier Analysis (Anselin Local Moran's I)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/cluster-and-outlier-analysis-anselin-local-moran-s.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the newest version of ArcGIS (not sure if it's limited to ArcGIS Pro as of now), ModelBuilder is supposed to have the ability to handle iterations. See: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm

Comment: It is limited to arcgis pro. But thanks anyway